# Resize (width/height) image with PHP

Tags: php, image

I have a code that only upload image but doesn't resize (width/height) the image.

I tried [this](http://www.9lessons.info/2009/03/upload-and-resize-image-with-php.html) solution and embed it but it is not working.

Can anyone find a solution for me.

**This is my original Code**

**File Name:** avatar.php

```
<?php
// declare variables
$msg = '';
$f_avatar_image = '';
// ------------------------------------------------------------
// UPLOAD AVATAR
// ------------------------------------------------------------
if(isset($_POST['btnUploadAvatar']) && !empty($_FILES['fileUpload']['name']))
{
    // create variables
    $avatar_directory = AVATAR_FILE_DIRECTORY;
    $file_name = $_FILES['fileUpload']['name'];
    $file_type = $_FILES['fileUpload']['type'];
    $file_size = $_FILES['fileUpload']['size'];
    $file_size_limit = AVATAR_FILE_SIZE;
    $calc_kilobites = 1024;
    $file_size_kb = round($file_size / $calc_kilobites, 2);
    $temp_file_name = $_FILES['fileUpload']['tmp_name'];
    $upload_error = $_FILES['fileUpload']['error'];


    // create unique file name
    $unique_file_name = $user_name.'-'.$file_name;
    $avatar_img_url = AVATAR_IMAGE_URL.$user_name.'-'.$file_name;

    // if upload error display error message
    if($upload_error > 0)
    {
        echo 'ERROR:' . $upload_error;
    }

    // if no upload error - check for file types
    if($upload_error == 0 &&
    $file_type == 'image/gif' ||
    $file_type == 'image/jpeg' ||
    $file_type == 'image/png' )
    {
        // if file size is within limits
        if($file_size <= $file_size_limit)
        {
            // move uploaded file to assigned directory
            if(move_uploaded_file($temp_file_name, $avatar_directory . $unique_file_name))

            {
                // get user id
                $get_user_id = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT UserId FROM users WHERE UserName = '$user_name' Limit 1") or die($dataaccess_error);

                // if user id exist
                if(mysqli_num_rows($get_user_id) == 1 )
                {
                    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($get_user_id);
                    $user_id = $row['UserId'];

                    // check if user profile already exist
                    $check_user_profile = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT UserId FROM profiles WHERE UserName = '$user_name' Limit 1") or die($dataaccess_error);

                    // if user profile exist - update
                    if(mysqli_num_rows($check_user_profile) == 1 )
                    {
                        // update profiles
                        $update_profile = mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE profiles SET AvatarImage = '$avatar_img_url' WHERE UserName = '$user_name'") or die($dataaccess_error);

                        if(mysqli_affected_rows($conn) > 0)
                        {
                            echo 'Upload Success! <br/>';
                            echo 'File Name: '.$file_name.'<br/>';
                            echo 'File Type: '.$file_type.'<br/>';
                            echo 'File Size: '.$file_size_kb.' Kb <br/>';
                            $msg = $profile_update_success;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $msg = $profile_update_failed;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // create profile
                        $insert_profile = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO profiles(UserId,UserName,AvatarImage) VALUES($user_id,'$user_name','$avatar_img_url')") or die($dataaccess_error);

                        if(mysqli_affected_rows($conn) > 0)
                        {
                            echo 'Upload Success! <br/>';
                            echo 'File Name: '.$file_name.'<br/>';
                            echo 'File Type: '.$file_type.'<br/>';
                            echo 'File Size: '.$file_size_kb.' Kb <br/>';
                            $msg = $profile_update_success;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $msg = $profile_create_failed;
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    // user id not found
                    $msg = $profile_update_failed2;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                $msg = $avatar_upload_failed;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $msg = $avatar_file_too_large;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $msg = $avatar_wrong_file_type;
    }
}
elseif(isset($_POST['btnUploadAvatar']) && empty($_FILES['fileUpload']['name']))
{
    $msg = $avatar_empty;
}


// ------------------------------------------------------------
// DISPLAY AVATAR ON PAGE LOAD
// ------------------------------------------------------------
if($user_name)
{
    // get user id
    $get_avatar_image = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT AvatarImage FROM profiles WHERE UserName = '$user_name' Limit 1") or die($dataaccess_error);

    if(mysqli_num_rows($get_avatar_image) == 1)
    {
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($get_avatar_image);
        if($row['AvatarImage'] != 'NULL' && $row['AvatarImage'] != '')
        {
            $f_avatar_image = $row['AvatarImage'];
        }
        else
        {
            $f_avatar_image = AVATAR_IMAGE_URL.DEFAULT_AVATAR_IMAGE;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $f_avatar_image = AVATAR_IMAGE_URL.DEFAULT_AVATAR_IMAGE;
    }
}
?>
```

**This is the code that i want to embed it**

```
    error_reporting(0);

    $change="";
    $abc="";


     define ("MAX_SIZE","400");
     function getExtension($str) {
             $i = strrpos($str,".");
             if (!$i) { return ""; }
             $l = strlen($str) - $i;
             $ext = substr($str,$i+1,$l);
             return $ext;
     }

     $errors=0;




     if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
     {
        $image =$_FILES["file"]["name"];
        $uploadedfile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];


        if ($image) 
        {

            $filename = stripslashes($_FILES['file']['name']);

            $extension = getExtension($filename);
            $extension = strtolower($extension);


     if (($extension != "jpg") && ($extension != "jpeg") && ($extension != "png") && ($extension != "gif")) 
            {

                $change='<div class="msgdiv">Unknown Image extension </div> ';
                $errors=1;
            }
            else
            {

     $size=filesize($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);


    if ($size > MAX_SIZE*1024)
    {
        $change='<div class="msgdiv">You have exceeded the size limit!</div> ';
        $errors=1;
    }


    if($extension=="jpg" || $extension=="jpeg" )
    {
    $uploadedfile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $src = imagecreatefromjpeg($uploadedfile);

    }
    else if($extension=="png")
    {
    $uploadedfile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $src = imagecreatefrompng($uploadedfile);

    }
    else 
    {
    $src = imagecreatefromgif($uploadedfile);
    }

    echo $scr;

    list($width,$height)=getimagesize($uploadedfile);


    $newwidth=150;
    $newheight=($height/$width)*$newwidth;
    $tmp=imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth,$newheight);


    $newwidth1=50;
    $newheight1=($height/$width)*$newwidth1;
    $tmp1=imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth1,$newheight1);

    imagecopyresampled($tmp,$src,0,0,0,0,$newwidth,$newheight,$width,$height);

    imagecopyresampled($tmp1,$src,0,0,0,0,$newwidth1,$newheight1,$width,$height);


    $filename = "profile.pic/profile/big" .date('Y-m-d_His - '). $_FILES['file']['name'];

    $filename1 = "profile.pic/header/small".date('Y-m-d_His - '). $_FILES['file']['name'];

    // mysql_query("update {$prefix}users set img='$big',img_small='$small' where user_id='$user'");
$change=' Image Uploaded Successfully!';




    imagejpeg($tmp,$filename,100);

    imagejpeg($tmp1,$filename1,100);

    imagedestroy($src);
    imagedestroy($tmp);
    imagedestroy($tmp1);
    }}

    }

    //If no errors registred, print the success message
     if(isset($_POST['Submit']) && !$errors) 
     {

       // mysql_query("update {$prefix}users set img='$big',img_small='$small' where user_id='$user'");
        $change=' <div class="msgdiv">Image Uploaded Successfully!</div>';
     }
```

Comment: I just need to embed the second code into the avatar.php file.

Answer (score 0):

Just simple. From your above code we will get an image URL in a variable and we can use that in out resize function like this

$imgUrl = 'http://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/2010Redesign/images/LangugeHomePages/PHP.png';

Now in html just make the following chnages

" height="50" width="50" />

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, if i do like that then my site will go slow because if a user upload a 2mb image profile so then 2mb profile image will load all the time in my website that will case the website to run slower.

Answer (score 0):

Imagemagick has always been very helpful for me! For example, from sitepoint:

```
$inFile = "test.jpg";
$outFile = "test-thumbnail.jpg";
$image = new Imagick($inFile);
$image->thumbnailImage(200, 200);
$image->writeImage($outFile);
```

A very good tutorial here: http://www.sitepoint.com/crop-and-resize-images-with-imagemagick/

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks but i want to use pure php and ajax to do it, because my server doesn't have imagemagick